# How to give the svg text property as zooming effect?

Tags: html, svg

How to give the svg text property zooming. I have tried to code in svg but it is not working. I have tool there they can drag the text. when they are dragging it is adding itemzoom as property but it is not working in illustrator or browser rendered output svg file. how to give correct syntax for text while it is in zoom effect

```
<text fill="#000000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="194" y="420" text-anchor="left" font-size="90.75" font-family="Casablanca" data-textcurve="0" data-itemzoom="1 1" itemzoom="0.5050505050505051 0.543010752688172">Test</text>
```

Comment: Whatever you are doing is (as you have discovered) specific to the tool you are using. There is no correct SVG syntax as there is no such feature in SVG. You could code your own using javascript of course.

Comment: is there any property which will show text as bigger

Comment: transform="scale(2)"